# getting first column of a matching line in bash

Tags: linux, bash, string-matching

I am getting an output from a shell command, and want to incorporate the first column of a matching line into a second command.  Here is what I have, and it works:

```
kubectl get pods -n system | while read string; do


if [[ "$string" == my-pod-* && "$string" == *Running* ]]; then
  #  echo $string
  read -ra ADDR <<< "$string"

  echo
  echo "--- Reading logs for ${ADDR[0]} ---"

  # desired output: kubectl -n system logs my-pod-123 --tail=5 -f
  kubectl -n system logs ${ADDR[0]} --tail=5 -f

fi


done
```

the output from first command would look something like this:

```
name           status      namespace       running
my-pod-123     Running     system          4h31m      #<<I want this one
another-pod-5  Running     system          5h15m
my-pod-023     Terminating system          8h05m
```

given that the output will contain only one match, is there a shorter way to do this without looping like this?  Thanks in advance for helping me improve my Bash skills as this seems very clumsy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `awk` like this:

```sh
name=$(kubectl get pods -n system | awk '/^my-pod.*Running/{print $1}')
[[ -n $name ]] && kubectl -n system logs "$name" --tail=5 -f
```

`awk` command will match pattern `my-pod.*Running` at the start of a line and if it is found then it will print first column. We store that in variable `name`.

If `$name` is not empty then we call `kubectl -n system logs` using that value.

Comment: This is definitely leaner than what I had, thanks! This also helps me visualize use of `awk` for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

How about `grep`?

```sh
wanted=$(kubectl get pods -n system | grep 'my-pod-.*Running')
```

Can do error checking at the same time:

```sh
if ! wanted=$(kubectl get pods -n system | grep 'my-pod-.*Running'); then
    echo "Error: no running my-pods" >&2
fi
```